# TeamCity: is it possible to to use Subversion SVN from a file:// share?

Tags: file, svn, teamcity

Is it possible to use SVN as source control for a project, but instead of connecting to `svn://servername`, I would like to connect to `file://servername/SourceControl/SourceDb` share. But apparently this is not supported?

[image: teamcity - svn]

Gives error message:
[image: teamcity - error]

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity is trying to protect you from yourself. While Subversion does (or at least used to) support repository databases placed on file shares, doing so is very dangerous:

- A single keystroke (intentional or otherwise) by *anyone* with access to the repository will render history lost at best, and the repository useless at worst
- Path-based authorization cannot be enforced
- Hook scripts can easily be bypassed
- Depending on how the share is hosted, [various problems may crop up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15191620/1324345)

From the [Subversion manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.recommendations):

> Do not be seduced by the simple idea of having all of your users access a repository directly via file:// URLs. Even if the repository is readily available to everyone via a network share, this is a bad idea. It removes any layers of protection between the users and the repository: users can accidentally (or intentionally) corrupt the repository database, it becomes hard to take the repository offline for inspection or upgrade, and it can lead to a mess of file permission problems

Stand up a proper server.